# What is the difference between WebRTC offer and answer?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, p2p, sdp

I am trying to add audio/video chat feature using WebRTC to existing text chat app. Chat room participants already are chatting, but when they decide they need audio/video, they press a button to start audio/video. Whichever client presses a button, I am calling `myPeerConnection.createOffer().then(function(offer){setLocalDescription(offer)}` and then sending the `offer` (JSON.stringified) to the server along with clientID. After `X` seconds, I disable the button to join the audio/video chat, send a notice to the server to distribute all the `offers` to the participants. At this point, all the clients willing to join audio/video chat have entire set of SDPs from all the remaining peers.

My question is, do I need to send answers to each offer from each client? My understanding is that SDP describes capabilities of the client to handle audio/video. Can I use the offer SDPs from others to `setRemoteDescription(SDP)`? All the examples, tutorials, questions, and posts I came across are using the paradigm of offer/answer and none of them are talking about what the difference between offer and answer is. Any information or pointers are appreciated.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkgf0vLh/3/) code segment simplified from my code. Please take a look at the console output, which shows nothing other than media capabilities. All the ICE and networking information which might distinguish SDPs comes after exchanging this offer SDP and the answer, so that is not yet part of this offer (and answer) exchange done through signaling channel.

PS: Strictly speaking, my scenario does not have any initiator or sender that is starting the channel. All participants are equal. No way to determine or sequence them either. When capabilities and network info are exchanged properly, they start audio/video chat.

Answer (score 0):

The SDP contains some elements which are the same for all participants -- like the supported codecs.
There are other elements (or rather lines) which are specific to the peerconnection instance. The ice candidates (ip/port) and ice-ufrag/ice-pwd in particular. These can not be shared across peerconnection.

(partly that is an implementation detail; see the webrtc forking group interim [meeting slides/recording](https://www.w3.org/2011/04/webrtc/wiki/July_8_2020) on ice-forking)

Comment: thanks for the link. ICE info is not part of the offer/answer exchange done through the signaling channel. Please check the jsFiddle I made to illustrate the contents of the SDP when `.createOffer()` is called. Just after calling createOffer(), SDP has no info about the ICE/IPs/Ports, which will be sent to the peer, and the answer SDP generated by peer also does not have them. As far as I can tell, ICE (STUN/TURN server info) is not needed when calling createOffer() and createAnswer() methods.

Comment: the ice-ufrag and ice-pwd is part of the signaling information. And candidates need to be signalled at some point in order to establish a connection.

Comment: Sorry for this novice question, but I could not figure out which part in this OFFER SDP is ufrag/pwd. `"OFFER: v=0
o=- 7352028919973714015 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
"` Same goes with ANSWER SDP too. I am unable to see any difference between offer and answer except for the 'type' during signaling. I don't know if my SDP object is missing something, but this is what is being exchanged in my case during signaling before ICE comes into picture. Please advice if I am missing some values in this SDP.